# Is asking for a proof to be written on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a rather complicated (relatively speaking) calculus equation that is true for all values greater then 0. I want to write a proof but the calculus is getting rather advanced. Is asking for a proof to be written on topic?

Comment: Asking here to avoid getting shut down :P

Comment: Is this a "do my homework for me" problem?  If not, when you post it explain why not.  And show your attempts.

Comment: @GEdgar it is not a do my homework. It is a hey that may work problem.

Comment: If you can make it clear that it's not homework and that you actually have reason to believe it not just for the values you've tried (depending on the complexity of the equation) and explain why you need a proof, I guess it will be on topic.

Comment: So long as it's a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) and on-topic, it should be fine. See also: ([tag:proof-writing])

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me to be precisely the kind of question we at Math SE love to answer. To receive the best response, please include the context of the question, such as where it came from, what level your understanding is at, and how you tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: when you said MSE i thought meta stack exchange and i got confused :P i was wondering how I was supposed to try and solve this problem